# Handling sessions in jQuery Mobile and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, session, mobile

I'm writing a JQM web app with a PHP web service. Users will be able to sign-in and register that they've made a purchase of, for instance, a soda from the club. This info will be stored in a database and eventually billed.

To illustrate what I want to do: I have already implemented this as an Android app. My "session handling" in the Android app consists of simply storing the user's credentials in Android's savedPeferences (persistent local storage) upon succesful authentication with the server. These credentials are then resent with every subsequent server request so that users only ever have to sign-in once - upon running the app for the first time.

I want to mimic this behavior in my JQM app as closely as possible. Ideally, the user should only ever have to sign in once unless they choose log out.

I'm a bit rusty when it comes to website programming, so what would be the best approach? Non-expiring cookings? Do I use a PHP session or handle everything in javascript?

This is for a hobby project; I prefer a simple solution over something overly secure and complex. Thanks!

Edit: After reading Mike's answer I stumbled across this plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
Perhaps this is the easiest way to keep users logged in..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP sessions are going to be invalidated after a set amount of time (depending on your php.ini settings or any runtime modificatoins to the settings).

You can use long-time expiring cookies to persist a login (typically user is given checkbox at login to allow their login credential to be stored).

Since you are developing for a mobile device, you do also have the alternative of using HTML5 local storage since most every Android browser out there supports it. See more info at the link below.

[HTML5 Local storage info](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp)

I prefer this as the login hash could be persisted even if the user clears their browser cookies and it can be handled strictly within Javascript.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of HTML5 Local storage, but I'm tring to support several different mobile platforms (even Symbian), and I figure that I can't count on HTML5 support everywhere. However, iOS is my main focus.

Comment: iOS support HTML5 local storage as does the modern Symbian browser. Really anything based on Web Kit should be OK to use, though you can obviously check compatibility.

Comment: I did end up using Web Storage (both localstorage and sessionstorage) for my app instead of cookies. It seems to be supported in pretty much any browser that has received an update in the last 3 years. However, I found that web storage is diabled in iOS when "private browsing" is enabled, so one must remember to handle those cases with an error message.